# F# suitable container for (string, float, float) triads?

Tags: f#, deedle

I have the following problem and I hope somebody can help me.

Short description of the problem: i need to store a (string A, float B, float C) triad into a suitable container. The triad originates fomr a double "for" loop. 
But the essential point is that I will need to slice this container when the loops are over to perform other operations.

An example that can be executed from the .fsx shell (using Deedle frames) follows. The triad is what is beeing printed on the screen.

```
open Deedle

let categorical_variable = [| "A"; "B"; "C"; "A"; "B"; "C"; |]
let vec_1 = [| 15.5; 14.3; 15.5; 14.3; 15.5; 14.3; |]
let vec_2 = [| 114.3; 17.5; 9.3; 88.7; 115.5; 12.3; |]

let dframe = frame ["cat" =?> Series.ofValues categorical_variable
                    "v1" =?> Series.ofValues vec_1
                    "v2" =?> Series.ofValues vec_2 ]

let distinct_categorical_variables = categorical_variable |> Array.toSeq |> Seq.distinct |> Seq.toArray

let mutable frame_slice : Frame<int, string> = Frame.ofRows []
let mutable frame_slice_vec_1 : float[] = Array.empty
let mutable frame_slice_vec_1_distinct : float[] = Array.empty

for cat_var in distinct_categorical_variables do

    frame_slice <- (dframe |> Frame.filterRowValues (fun row -> row.GetAs "cat" = cat_var))
    frame_slice_vec_1 <- (frame_slice?v1).Values |> Seq.toArray
    frame_slice_vec_1_distinct <- (frame_slice_vec_1 |> Array.toSeq |> Seq.distinct |> Seq.toArray)

    for vec_1_iter in frame_slice_vec_1_distinct do

        printfn "%s, %f, %f \n"  cat_var vec_1_iter (Array.average ((frame_slice?v2).Values |> Seq.toArray) ) |> ignore
```

So, is there any suitable object where to store this triad? I saw Array3d objects, but I don't think they are the right solution cause A, B and C of my triad have different types.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably want a [sequence expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx) with [tuples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233200.aspx):

```
let mySequence = 
  seq { for cat_var in distinct_categorical_variables do
          ...
          for vec_1_iter in ... do
            yield cat_var, vec_1_iter, Array.average ... }

// then use it like
for cat_var, vec_1_iter, result in mySequence do
  ...
```

Comment: @tinoswe Note you may also want to call `Seq.toList` on that.  As-is, a raw `seq` is lazy, meaning it'll get recalculated each time you iterate through it.  If you make it a `list` then it'll store the results in memory rather than recalculating.  (Which may or may not be desirable depending on your memory constraints).